# Return array of all div class names from html source using php

Tags: php, dom, xpath

from a html source, using dom and xpath how would I return an array containing all the div class names?  I use the following which returns all the div class names that contain "XX", but don't know the query to use for $targets to return all.  I know this should be simple but I can't find one that works.

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($data);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
   $targets = $xpath->query(".//div[contains(@class, 'XX')]");
   $classNames_array = array();
   foreach ($targets as $target) {
   $classNames_array[] = $target->textContent;
   }
   print_r(array_values($classNames_array));
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can just continue using a loop, then use [`->getAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) and target the class

Comment: @Kevin, Could you please elaborate?  With the div classes, I don't know their names.   I am looking for the xpath query to return array of all div class names from the html source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for all classes of divs would be `'//div/@class'`. Then you get a [DomAttr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr) list which you can iterate and get the value as a public property, e.g.

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $classes[] = $entry->value;
}
```